# Having trouble with using one variable with 4 seperate ID's in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want my code to run the `click` variable separately for each time a new ID is being clicked on:

```
var click = 0;
$("#head, #mouth, #nose, #eyes").click(function () {
  if (click < 9) {
    $(this).animate({left: "-=367px"}, 500);
    click++;
  } else {
    $(this).animate({left: "0px"}, 500);
    click = 0;
  }
});
```

At the moment, every time an ID is clicked, that same `click` variable increments by 1 no matter which ID is being clicked. Wasn't sure on how to code this part without having to make 4 separate functions that do the same thing (wanted to reduce code redundancy).

Comment: You could use event.target to know which id has been clicked. You can find the details here for jquery : https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could identify the id of the target and then access an object based on that ID to get the `click`:

```
const clicks = {};
$("#head, #mouth, #nose, #eyes").click(function () {
  const { id } = this;
  const clickCount = clicks[id] || 0;
  if (clickCount < 9) {
    $(this).animate({left: "-=367px"}, 500);
    clicks[id] = clickCount + 1;
  } else {
    $(this).animate({left: "0px"}, 500);
    clicks[id] = 0;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 elements, so you will need 4 variables. Or you can have an array/object with 4 items/properties. I like using an object for this rather than an array because you can use the elements' IDs as the keys of the object:

```
var clicks = {};
$("#head, #mouth, #nose, #eyes").click(function() {
  var id = this.id;
  clicks[id] = clicks[id] || 0;
  if (clicks[id] < 9) {
    $(this).animate({left: "-=367px"}, 500);
    clicks[id]++;
  } else {
    $(this).animate({left: "0px"}, 500);
    clicks[id] = 0;
  }
});
```